# How to change the email sender name in all emails in magento?

Tags: email, magento, header, mail-sender

I have set emails in magento 2

but I want to edit the sender name in Email.

How I change the sender name in magento 2?

Answer (score 0):

You can change sender name in Magento by going to Configuration, under General tab -> Store email addresses. There you can change email id and sender name accordingly for different users.

Comment: do you know about laravel

Comment: can i get your email